# Reactor Core flux: difference between FluxSink.OverflowStrategy and onBackPressure*?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have below code:

```
Flux.create(sink -> ..., FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST)
...
.onBackpressureLatest()
.subscribe();
```

What is the difference in Flux behaviour if I specify `FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST` vs. `.onBackpressureLatest()`?

And if I specify, for example, both `FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST` and `.onBackpressureBuffer()`, what would it do?